# No HDMI out displaying after boot up screen

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, display, boot-issues, vnc

I normally use VNC to connect to my Pi so I have not used the HDMI out in the past couple of weeks. When I first set up my Pi I did it using the same display and HDMI cable I am trying to use now (and that successfully worked with my Apple TV).

For some reason when my Pi boots up I see all of the boot up screens (the Raspberry Pi logo, etc...) But once it gets past that it stops displaying anything at all. I am still able to connect to it and use it through VNC but I'm not sure why the HDMI just stops working halfway through the boot up. I have tried swapping out the cable and rebooting several times. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not a power supply issue. There is something about VNC / TeamViewer that causes this HDMI issue which makes it stop working halfway through the boot up. This issue is still OPEN

Comment: Can you connect a keyboard and try Ctrl+F1 to see if you can get back to tty1 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you had been using VNC without a display connected, it likely that you selected a particular display resolution, as the default resolution that you get without a display is very low.

However, your display may not support this resolution. You could try running raspi-config, going to Advanced > Resolution and setting this back to "default", allowing your display to choose a resolution that it supports.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a different power supply? HDMI output consumes a lot of power so if you have a poor power supply in can't provide enough power to the output. Your are still able to SSH to RaspberryPi, but the display won't work. The HDMI cable doesn't matter that much if it can display the logo, it will display everything else.

Comment: Unfortunately  I don't have a second power supply to try at this time but I tried connecting it to a smaller TV today which worked. I think you're right that there is a power issue because it probably has more trouble getting enough power to display on the large TV I'm trying to connect it to. It was working on the large TV a couple of weeks ago though so I'm not sure why it would be any worse off now. I'm going to buy a new power supply and see if it helps.